# i am working on django forms with the password related

Tags: django, forms, web

how  i can set  my own password at any login template in my django website without using django default login authentication.
A sample of my website is given in screen shot of my project.I want to set  a own password in that page.[sample of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLl2x.png)

Answer (score -2):

so i guess you want to create a login using your own password from within the website without using Django shell.

1. In-order to achieve the above you can use a registration page (html) to accept the username/user id and the password.[image: Sample]
   **form HTML code**

```
                <form action="{% url 'reg_method' %}" method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-group"><label for="name">Name</label><input class="form-control item" type="text" id="name" name="name"></div>
                    <div class="form-group"><label for="password">Password</label><input class="form-control item" type="password" id="password" name="password"></div>
                    <div class="form-group"><label for="email">Email</label><input class="form-control item" type="email" id="email" name="email"></div><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
                </form>
```

2. In `urls.py`

```py
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index ,name='index'),
    path('auth_reg',views.reg_method ,name='reg_method'),
]
```

3. In your app's `views.py` define a method for processing the request from registration page.

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def reg_method(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('name') and request.POST.get('password') and request.POST.get('email'):
            name = request.POST.get('name')
            password = request.POST.get('password')
            email = request.POST.get('email')

            User.objects.create_user(username=name, email=email, password=password, )
            return HttpResponse('User successfully created')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('User details are not entered')
```

4. Now you can use your login page to login the site using the username/id and password that you have used to register.
   [image]

PS: additionally you can use the **Authentication** method to check whether the user exists or not. by importing.,

```py
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
```